# Adding incremental attributes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I add incrementing IDs to each pair of elements (a/div), and hide/show the `div` when clicking on the link before it using toogle?

Here's the current HTML and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ayuda">
    <a>My help n1</a>
    <div>
         Content help n1
    </div>
    <br />
    <a>My help n2</a>
    <div>Content help n2</div>
</div>
<script>
var ayuda = $(".ayuda a").length;           // contar el número de columnas
for (var i=0;i<ayuda;++i)                   // help trae la cantidad de p
{
   (function(j) {                         // creando IDs dinámicos segúna la cantidad de columnas
        $('.ayuda a').attr('id', 'mi_ayuda_'+j);
        $('.ayuda a').attr('href', '#');
        $('.ayuda div').attr('id', 'mi_ayuda_contenido_'+j);
        $("#mi_ayuda_contenido_"+j).hide();
            $("#mi_ayuda_"+j).click(function () {
                window.alert(j); 
                $("#mi_ayuda_contenido_"+(j) ).toggle();    
            });
    })(i);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AzcHv/).

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop the elements, add the IDs and attach the event.

```
$(function() {
    $(".ayuda a").each(function(i,el) {
        $(el).attr('id','mi_ayuda_'+i)
             .attr('href', '#')
             .next()
               .attr('id', 'mi_ayuda_contenido_'+i)
               .hide();
        $(el).click(function () {
            window.alert(i); 
            $("#mi_ayuda_contenido_"+ i).toggle();    
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle  Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/N5BU3/)

Answer (score 3):

No need to add IDs; you cant just attach event listeners to the link objects. Best to always use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) when attaching event listeners to support dynamically added elements.

```
$("div.ayuda").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  $(this).next("div").toggle();
});
```

And for initially hiding the divs inside the ayuda div, best to add CSS to avoid messy animation of hiding these divs on load of the page.

```
div.ayuda > div {
  display: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D9xhU/)

Answer (score 1):

Because inside the for loop, instead of targetting only the element at the current index, you are targetting all elements matching the given selector

You can solve it much easily using

```
$(".ayuda a").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle()
}).attr('href', '#').next().hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PzU6t/)

Your code should look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PzU6t/3/)